# To include space after 8 characters each time in a single word that contains 1040 character using excel or any text editor tool

Tags: excel, excel-formula, text-editor, webtextedit

I am trying to add space after 8 characters in sequence to a single word consist of 1040 characters. I dont want to write code in any of the programming language since this process required frequently not using technical programs. Can someone please suggest me any excel formulas or functions or any plugins like Kutools for excel or any text editor tool can be used to fix this issue.

For example:

```
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
```

I tried using kutools text features

[image]

but that returns the value with space only after first 8 characters and its not getting in sequence till the last character. Tried excel formulas like trim and replace that is also not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(LEN(A1)/8,0),,,8),8))
```

You'll notice a stray single 7 at the end of the string since your sample data is not 1040 but 1033 characters long.

If your input is always going to be 1040 characters long, then you can use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(130,,,8),8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Single Cell Formula:

```
=LET(
    x, A1,
    a, WRAPROWS(MID(x, SEQUENCE(LEN(x)), 1), 8),
    b, CONCAT(TOCOL(HSTACK(a, IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)), " ")), 2)),
    b
)
```